# Angular ng-keyup not working when calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="keywords" ng-keyup="search()">
```

It doesn't call the search function where as, if I do ng-click="search()" it does work. Why is this?

Comment: Can't say without more information. What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: Just thinking, surely this should work if ng-click works?

Comment: Absolutely. The problem isn't here, I think. Can you make a fiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: Check out my site: http://elliottcoe.com/search/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-keyup` works perfectly fine for me. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/r74a5m25/

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello:
    <input ng-model="testModel" ng-keyup="search()"/>
</div>


function MyCtrl($scope, $log) {

    $scope.search = function() {
        alert('test');  
    };
}
```

---

Make sure you have an up to date version of angular in order to use `ng-keyup`. It looks like it has been available since version `1.0.8`.

Comment: Here's my site: http://elliottcoe.com/search/index.html I've taken the ng-click out of the submit button and put ng-keyup in the text input.

Comment: You are using a very old version of angular. Update it and your code should work.

Comment: I updated to a new version but now ng-bind-html-unsafe doesn't work, how do I get it to work with out having to make ridiculous changes to my controller?

Comment: It looks like this question has been answered then. You now should ask a completely new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `$watch` your variable

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('search.input',function(){
   $scope.doSearch('watched!'); //call your function here
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ابحث" ng-model="search.input">
```

Comment: The value will change when key-up, down or press. This is better for searching for my opinion.

Comment: I believe so, but note you may have problems using $watch when dealing with a ng-model appended to a input with attributes, max, min, step, maxlength. Once you do not follow these attributes (e.g. Input: 20 when the is max="10") the ng-model ends up undefined, and the $watch will stop being triggered, but that's just my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I never tried $watch with strict on inputs.